# Imported csv file remains a flat table in R studio

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, read.csv

I have a CSV file with the format as this:

```
"Timestamp,Data,Quality"
"04/10/21 11:00:00,0.000000,0"
"04/10/21 11:02:00,0.014652,1"
"04/10/21 11:03:00,0.009768,1"
"04/10/21 11:04:00,0.014652,1"
    .
    .
    .
```

In order to import it into R, and turn it to dataframe this is what I do.

```
library('tidyverse')
library('ggplot2')
library(dplyr)

mydata<-read.csv('C:/Users/tesge/Desktop/tnc results/syabas hydrotest/output/rev1/1/D2104100-3.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringAsFactors = FALSE) 

mydata
```

But the output that i got, is still not in a proper table format, in separate 3 columns.
The result:

```
> head(mydata)
     ï..Timestamp.Data.Quality
1 04/10/21 11:00:00,0.000000,0
2 04/10/21 11:02:00,0.014652,1
3 04/10/21 11:03:00,0.009768,1
4 04/10/21 11:04:00,0.014652,1
5 04/10/21 11:05:00,0.009768,1
6 04/10/21 11:07:00,0.000000,0
```

I am not sure why the first column header has got strange characters there.
New here. Kindly enlighten me on this. Thanks in advance.
Link to the csv file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jim1ryaq2azulqg/D2104100-3.csv?dl=0

Comment: because your csv is not formatted in a way as you suggest in your question. Your first column contains all the variables. This is ok, just split the resulting column by fixed delimiters. Either read in as fixed delimited file, or do it after reading.

Comment: The "strange characters" at the start of the file are called UTF8 BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

read_csv("D2104100-3.csv") %>%
  separate(
    col = 1,
    into = c("Timestamp", "Data", "Quality"),
    sep = ","
  ) %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = dmy_hms(Timestamp),
         Data = as.numeric(Data),
         Quality = as.integer(Quality))
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   `Timestamp,Data,Quality` = col_character()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 1,466 x 3
#>    Timestamp              Data Quality
#>    <dttm>                <dbl>   <int>
#>  1 2021-10-04 11:00:00 0             0
#>  2 2021-10-04 11:02:00 0.0147        1
#>  3 2021-10-04 11:03:00 0.00977       1
#>  4 2021-10-04 11:04:00 0.0147        1
#>  5 2021-10-04 11:05:00 0.00977       1
#>  6 2021-10-04 11:07:00 0             0
#>  7 2021-10-04 11:08:00 0.00977       1
#>  8 2021-10-04 11:14:00 0.0147        1
#>  9 2021-10-04 11:16:00 0.00977       1
#> 10 2021-10-04 11:22:00 0.00488       1
#> # ... with 1,456 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

All rows are in quotes. Remove them and it should work.

In CSV, quotes are used to delimit columns containing commas, which means your CSV actually contains only one column.